# Running an iterative command in Python for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I want to execute a command iteratively using for loop. For example, "axi.tick_params(labelbottom=False)"....

where 'i' in the 'axi' represents number of iterations. How can I do this in the simplest way?

Comment: Perhaps make `ax` as a list. Then you can access them in your for loop as such: `ax[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, you have a number of different variables `ax1, ax2,..., axn` and you want to execute the command for each one of them. If this is the case, you can save all the variables in one list and then iterate over it.

```
variables = [ax1, ax2, ax3, ...] #add your variables to this list

for v in variables:
    v.tick_params(labelbottom=False)
```

In case you have one variable and you want to execute the same command a number of times:

```
n = 10 # number of times the command will be executed.
for i in range(n):
    ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False)
```